# How to number pages in a "book" format using the report document class?

Tags: page-numbering, typography

Consider section 2 in this website: https://latex-tutorial.com/page-numbering-latex/

I would like it just like that but with using report document class, how can I do this?

currently my numbering system starts with the abstract as page 1 and my first "actual" chapter is on page 10. I'd like my first actual chapter in Arabic numbering system as page 1 and the rest in Roman numbering system.

EDIT:

Using the book class:

```
\clearpage
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
```

This inst a MWE rather showing what is happening. The list of figures should start from vii and end at ix and the list of tables starts at x. However, when I run the code, the list of figures is shown on the contents line as ix, why?

EDIT 2:

I need a solution using report document class. I've seen previous articles in this format so I think it is doable.

Comment: Why not using the `book` class, then?

Comment: @egreg This would ruin my document I believe but I can try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want blank pages, you can tell the `book` class that your document is `oneside`. You can also simplify the input.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Abstract}

\chapter{Acknowledgments}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a typical page for this choice of the class.

[image]

If you pass `report` some options, just add `oneside` to them. So a call like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
```

would become

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
```

The corresponding code for `report` would be as follows.

```
\documentclass{report} % add the options you like
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\chapter{Abstract}

\chapter{Acknowledgments}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The output is very similar. Indeed, the differences between `report` and `book` are very minor. The former chooses `oneside` by default, whereas this has to be explicitly stated for the latter. With `book` you have `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` that do the right thing.

If you feel that the `book` class has too prominent titles, you can consider `amsbook` instead.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added the part about options. Please, remove all comments of yours that are now obsolete.